# FragmentPagerAdapter for sliding youtube video not work for second time

Tags: android, youtube

I want to create youtube video like slider, I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter inside fragment, it works for the first time, but when I replace it with another fragment, and back again, the frame is blank. I tried changing FragmentPagerAdapter into FragmentStatePagerAdapter, still it doesn't work. What am I missing? or any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Sorry for my english. It's not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved.

I re-set adapter in onResume method if adapter is not null. I do not know if it's a best way to solve this problem, but now it works.